# Retrieve all data from one table except for matching records from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, mysqli

I have two tables linked by by a column `cat_id`.  I want to retrieve all values of `timing` in **M_Master** for which no equivalent exists in **Tbl_Appointment**.

Example: **Tbl_Appointment** holds data for `timing` value `6:15 PM`. I want all `timing` values from **M_Master** except for `6:15 PM`.

Here is data from  **M_Master**

```
| id  | name  | timing   | cat_id | rate | design_template | type   | prefix | vat |
| 109 |       | 09:30 AM | 3      | 0    |                 | TIMING |        | 0   |
| 110 |       | 09:45 AM | 3      | 0    |                 | TIMING |        | 0   |
| 113 |       | 10:15 AM | 3      | 0    |                 | TIMING |        | 0   |
| 115 |       | 11:00 AM | 3      | 0    |                 | TIMING |        | 0   |
| 116 |       | 11:30 AM | 3      | 0    |                 | TIMING |        | 0   |
| 118 |       | 12:30 PM | 3      | 0    |                 | TIMING |        | 0   |
| 121 |       |  1:30 PM | 3      | 0    |                 | TIMING |        | 0   |
| 125 |       |  2:30 PM | 3      | 0    |                 | TIMING |        | 0   |
| 127 |       |  6:15 PM | 3      | 0    |                 | TIMING |        | 0   |
```

and here is data from **Tbl_Appointment**

```
| id | cancel | name  | mobileno   | age | sex | payment_told | test_id | referredby | app_given | sentsms | timing   | cat_id | app_date   |
| 94 | 0      | TEST2 | 7985462313 | 45  | 1   | 800.00       | 123     | 14         | QWERTY    | 1       | 06:15 PM | 3      | 2016-01-01 |
```

Comment: Add some more description what actually you want ?

Comment: so what is that except data?? please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: Especially for relatively short tables like these, you should post them as text, not as images. If you do use images, they should be inline. Please review the help files.

Comment: Is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0886d/1) going into the right direction?

Comment: Based on the update, what have you tried? My SQL is a bit rusty, but the easiest way to think about it is roughly something like `select timing from M_Master where timing not in (select timing from Tbl_Appointment);`  I'm sure you (or someone else) can take it from here and improve that (and work in the linking on `cat_id`)...

Comment: Thanks it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided so far, you could try along

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(M.timing, '%h:%i %p') AS timing
FROM M_Master M
JOIN Tbl_Appointment A
  ON M.cat_id = A.cat_id
  AND A.app_date = '2016-01-01'
  AND M.timing != A.timing
ORDER BY M.timing
;
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0886d/1).

Please comment if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.